# Did Søren Norby ever visit Iceland?

Tags: 16th-century, denmark, iceland

[Søren Norby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Norby) was the [Seignor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seignory) of Iceland 1515-1517. However, I can't find any information on whether he actually ever visited Iceland, had any actual powers in this role or if the position was a [sinecure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinecure).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like he did spend those years in Iceland. There are a few pages discussing his time there from 1515 in volume 3 of *[Historisk arkiv](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pn49AAAAYAAJ&dq=%22S%C3%B8ren%20Norby%22%20island&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* (Gbooks), p403-406

*[De tre nordiske rigers historie under Hans](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=U78OAAAAQAAJ&dq=%22S%C3%B8ren%20Norby%22%20island&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* by Carl Ferdinand Allen (Gbooks) pages 143-144 suggests that he did spend time there (without much detail about his stay).

The phrasing of a sentence in *[Danmarks historie](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=srSb3JNRGA4C&dq=%22S%C3%B8ren%20Norby%22%20island&source=gbs_navlinks_s)* by Ole Feldbæk (Gbooks) p65 also implies that he was based in Iceland until 1517 but then called south to help in the war against Sweden, which is discussed in somewhat different terms in the above Historisk arkiv pages.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. So he was sent there partly to deal with pirates. Interestingly enough, he later was involved in piracy. :-)